# Microsoft Speech Platform Error 404 at the official site

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform

I need to install the following packages in order to work with the Microsoft Speech Platform :

- Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime,
- Microsoft Speech Platform - SDK,
- Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime Languages.

I had done this about a year ago but today I can't find them on the Microsoft's website. When I try to get access in the old link, an `404 ERROR` occurred.

Is there any way to get these packages again?

Comment: You are right, all the links are dead (even their own). Could be that someone made a mistake of some description

Comment: IMHO not really a SO question. You should just contact MS support. Maybe there's a licensing issue. That means they're not allowed to distribute it anymore.

Comment: Hello, what kind of project do you use ? Which version of .NET ? System.Speech is included since Windows Vista in the .NET Framework 5.0. So you just have to create a .NET Framework 5.0 or greater project, then add the assembly System.Speech that is already shipped with .NET

Comment: Now i use .NET Framework 4.6.1, but I tried to run the project on version 5.0. If i run a project on a machine without these packages i get the following error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID CLSID {49428A60-C997-4D0E-9808-9E326C178D58}} failed due to the following error: 80040154 
When i try to do: SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci); as far as I understand this is what you need a file MSSpeech_SR_ru-RU_TELE.msi, but it disappeared from the official site.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them in the UCMA 4.0 SDK Setup [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35463)

Answer (score 0):

The links are dead.

According to these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-migrate-from-bing-speech), the **Speech service** is a possible replacement.

You can download the Speech SDK [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/).

Answer (score 0):

I see it being available at this site.

https://www.voiceelements.com/docs/programmable-voice/speech-recognition/install-microsoft-speech-platform/

Answer (score 0):

I have no inside knowledge, but I suspect the Microsoft acquisition of Nuance was the motivation for removing these downloads.

https://news.microsoft.com/2021/04/12/microsoft-accelerates-industry-cloud-strategy-for-healthcare-with-the-acquisition-of-nuance/